# How to show the picture of a post when it's link is hovered in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

There is a part in my website where the last 6 posts are reviewed and this is the HTML code for it:

```
<div class="latest-posts">
      <div id="latest-posts-title">
    <p>My Website's latest posts</p>
  </div>
      <div id="latest-posts-pictures"> <img src=""width="190px" height="190px" alt="latest-posts-pictures"> </div>
      <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Post1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Post2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Post3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Post4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Post5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Post6</a></li>
  </ul>
```

I want to add a feature to make the user able to see the post's picture when he/she hovers the post's link in the code above.

I've used this PHP code and it works well:

```
<ul>
<?php
$my_query = new WP_Query('showposts=6&cat=my_category');
while ($my_query->have_posts()):
$my_query->the_post();
$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;?>

<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

But this code does not contain the picture part that I want.
Do you know how can I make this feature available for my users?

> Please note that it is not important for me to use PHP or JavaScript, all I
>   want is to make it possible for the user to see the post's picture
>   when he hovers its link.

Comment: Does this get the image in your php code: $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full', false, '' );
echo '<img src="'.$src[0].'">';

Comment: @mikeg542 It didn't but I think with a few changes It will. thanks.

Comment: You can do this in a million different ways - But you need to get the featured image first - if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
 the_post_thumbnail_url('Whatever size you have here');
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can display featured image of the post using following code:

```
// Check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
}
```

You can check this link for more information.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/

Comment: Thanks but I want to add this feature when the user hovers the link. How can I implement that? I think it must be done using CSS or JS. Do you have any idea?

Comment: For this, You need to have some CSS or JS knowledge. For example you can print the image in a hidden `div` and the show the `div` when user hovered the post element. Something like following:
`.parent-class:hover .image-class{display: block}`

Comment: The php executes when the page is loaded - You need to have it already loaded in before hovereing - So this is the right way - Put that in a hidden div, and fade it in on hover.

Comment: Thank you, It's a nice idea. It works for me too 